# Use a proxy to connect iPhone to server?

Tags: iphone, proxy

I'm researching how to code an iPhone app that needs to connect to an online service to get data. The online service only provides access to specified IP addresses or ranges, so iPhones won't be able to connect directly, and the request will have to go through a server.  I looked into setting up my own forward proxy server (which the service in question are happy with, by the way), which I guess would do the job for most other platforms. Unfortunately the iPhone does not seem to allow configuring a proxy address programmatically. Is there another potential solution for accessing the content from an intermediate server, that would show the online service the IP address of the server, rather than each individual iPhone?

Many thanks

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that using cURL is one way to achieve this. There should be bindings available for Cocoa.

I'll let people know how it goes in the comments.

Steve